# Excel runtime Error while opening the copied workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have the workbook which opened and make copied by Save As option. When I am opening the saved workbook it's throwing an error

> Excel Select method of Worksheet class failed

and there is code as:

```
Sheets(sh_03).Select
```

If I replace the `Select` with `Activate` then it's working, but I don't know why. Also `sh_03` has been declared in Variables Declaration. This error occurs for most of the saved workbook which I am running in Bex tool Addins of SAP.

---

Other same issue with Pivot table refresh where its giving the error as

> object variable  or block variable not set

and code as:

```
For Each wks In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
```

If I replace the `Active` with `This` then again it's working, but I don't know the impact.

Let me know if any help which will be very much appreciated.

Thanks,
Harsh

Answer (score 0):

### Long Answer

`ActiveWorkbook` is the workbook that is currently active. It's relative and should probably not be used since you can't always be sure that it's going to point to the workbook you want, unless a line or two before you explicitly activated the workbook you are wanting to code against. Given that, switching to `ThisWorkbook`, which is the workbook that the code resides in, is a much safer bet. You should feel comfortable making that change.

As for the first error, because your `ActiveWorkbook` is not the same as `ThisWorkbook` (because of that second error), then we know that the workbook that we want isn't active at the moment. If you try to `SELECT` a sheet in a workbook that isn't in the `ActiveWorkbook` then you may get this error. Changing that code to `.Activate` is safer since `.Activate` will switch the `Activeworkbook` over to `ThisWorkbook` automagically and `.Select` the sheet.

### Short answer

Feel free to switch both of those as they are better solutions then the current code, since (as you've discovered) the current code is error prone in certain situations, like when the `ActiveWorkbook` is not `ThisWorkbook`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but the same code is working in the previous workbook without any issue and without any changes, is not that it should also work in copied workbook as well.

Comment: My point is that the code is kind of not great as-is. `ActiveWorkbook` is relative, and `sheetN.SELECT` will bomb if `sheetN` is not currently in the `ActiveWorkbook`. Your idea to switch to `Activate` and `ThisWorkbook` make the code much stronger and accomplish the same thing.